# How to reset the state of a StackNavigator nested in a DrawerNavigatior?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am building an app whose navigation is based on a DrawerNavigator from the react-navigation library.

This navigator has 3 tabs:

- 2 regular tabs
- 1 StackNavigator named "Search"

The StackNavigator consists of one screen that lets the user search for an item, and a second screen where the user sees the search results.

I do not want the search results page to be a tab of a DrawerNavigator, this is why I implemented this structure.

The problem is: if the user has already performed a search, when he clicks on the "Search" tab, he does not come back to the search screen but to the search results screen. I would prefer that the user comes back to the search screen.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this using navigation dispatch with navigationActions

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'DrawerScreen',
      params: {},
      action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SearchScreen' }),
    }),
  ],
})
navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Comment: For this I need to catch the click event on the Search tab in the DrawerNavigator. Do you know how can I catch this event?

Comment: Please have a look at this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801667/navigate-to-root-screen-from-nested-stack-navigator?noredirect=1#comment76584210_44801667

Answer (score 1):

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SearchScreen'})
  ]
})
```

Here in your button or any element with event add this:
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)

```
<Button
    onPress= {
        () => this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
    }
    title='Back to Search'
/>
```

Comment: Why would this work? I've been trying for days to achieve a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

**work for me**

```
const resetStackNavigator = (navigation, routeName) => {
          const resetAction = CommonActions.reset({
            index: 0, // Reset to the initial route (first screen)
            routes: [
              {
                name: routeName, 
              },
            ],
          });
        
          navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
        };
    
    
    
    import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
    
    const myScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>This is a stack screen </Text>
          <Button
            title="Reset StackNavigator"
           onPress={() => resetStackNavigator(navigation, '_ScreenNameToResetTo_')}
          />
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default myScreen;
```