# React Native React Navigation DrawerNavigator for spefific views

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to set and use DrawerNavigator but have it only show on my views once a user is logged in. For example not show up on login view or request password view.

I have the following DrawerNavigator

```
// Drawer Navigation
export const MainDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawer:{
                label: "Home",
            }
        },
    },
    Logout: {
        screen: Logout,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawer:{
                label: "Logout",
            }
        },
    }
});
```

and then my main navgation

```
// Main navigation StackNavigator
export const MainScreenNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Login",
            headerLeft: null
        },
    },
    ResetPassword: {
        screen: ResetPassword,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Reset Password",
            headerLeft: null
        },
    },
    Home: {
        screen: TabsNavigation,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Home",
            headerLeft: null,
        }
    }
});
```

My index file

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <MainScreenNavigator />
    }
}

export default App;
```

How can I render the drawer navigation? And how would I do for only spefic views

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801667/navigate-to-root-screen-from-nested-stack-navigator?noredirect=1#comment76584210_44801667

Check out this question , you will get to know how to add Drawer menu to specific navigator screens.

Comment: For better understanding you can check this demo :-
https://github.com/khle/easyRNRoute

And here is the blog link :-
https://medium.com/@kevinle/comprehensive-routing-and-navigation-in-react-native-made-easy-6383e6cdc293